# Cant run executables compiled by gcc on gc 4.8.2

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I did a fresh installation of minGW on windows 7 64 bits, I can compile c++ without errors, however if I try to run the executable, I get

"This version of D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Dropbox\c\rts\teste\a.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether  ou need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << "aaaa" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and I'm compiling using

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc -c D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Dropbox\c\rts\teste\a.cpp -o D:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Dropbox\c\rts\teste\a.exe

I believe GCC is not compiling 16 bit software, since its the last release

Comment: Delete the flag '-c'. Otherwise it does not create an executable. The flags -m31 or -m64 can be used to state whether you want to compile 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: -m32 worked, also I used g++ and removed the -c, thanks.